# Multiple hreflang on one page - duplicate content store views

Tags: magento2, sitemaps, hreflang

We have a Magento 2 shop in 3 languages `German`, `English` and `Spanish`.

Does it make sense to include all **hreflangs** for `Spanish` and `English` speaking countries in the sitemap?

Or would this lead to duplicate content according to you if we use the same let´s say `Spanish` page but include all possible country options?

Would you create new store views for each, even if the content is 1:1 same?

[image]